# Count matching values at same index

Tags: ruby

I have an array of symbols:

```
main_row = [:b, :r, :g, :o]
```

and another array `cells`, which is filled with instances of `Cell` class:

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :colour
  def initialize(colour = nil)
    @colour = colour
  end
end

cells = [Cell.new(:b), Cell.new(:g), Cell.new(:r), Cell.new(:o)]
```

I need to count how many elements in `cells` have the same colour as elements in `main_row` with the same index, and store them in variable called `correct`.

```
correct # => 2
```

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If
you [edit] your question to describe what you have tried so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cell = Struct.new(:colour)
cells = [Cell.new(:b), Cell.new(:g), Cell.new(:r), Cell.new(:o)]
main_row = [:b, :r, :g, :o] 

correct = cells.zip(main_row).count { |cell, colour| cell.colour == colour }
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cell = Struct.new(:colour)
cells = [Cell.new(:b), Cell.new(:g), Cell.new(:r), Cell.new(:o)]
main_row = [:b, :r, :g, :o].each

cells.count{|c| c.colour == main_row.next } # => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
main_row.each_index.count { |i| main_row[i] == cells[i].colour }
  #=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cells = [Cell.new(:b), Cell.new(:g), Cell.new(:r), Cell.new(:o)]
main_row = [:b, :r, :g, :o] 
cells.select.with_index { |c, i| i == main_row.index(c.colour) }.size
#=>2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cells = [Cell.new(:b), Cell.new(:g), Cell.new(:r), Cell.new(:o)]
main_row = [:b, :r, :g, :o]    
cells.map.with_index{ |c, i| i == main_row.index(c.colour) }.count(true)
#=> 2
```

Comment: second approach will fail if arrays include duplicates